# NLP model for binary classification outputs a class for each word

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, text-classification

I am basically running the code from Francois Chollet's Deep learning with python chapter 11.
It is a binary sentiment classification. For each sentence the label is 0 or 1.
After running the model as in the book, I try to make a prediction on one of the "validation" sentences.
The full code is a public kaggle notebook that can be found here:
https://www.kaggle.com/louisbunuel/deep-learning-with-python
It is part of the notebook here:
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter11_part02_sequence-models.ipynb

the only thing I added is my "extraction" of a tokenized sentence from the tokenized tensorflow dataset so that I can see an example of an output. I was expecting a number from 0 to 1 (a probability indeed) but instead I get an array of numbers from 0 to 1, one for each word in the sentence. In other words, it looks as if the model does not assign labels to each sentence but to each word.
Can anybody explain me what am I doing wrong? Is it my way of "extracting" a sentence from the tensorflow dataset?
Here's the code from the book/github, in the notebook

```
!curl -O https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
!tar -xf aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
!rm -r aclImdb/train/unsup


import os, pathlib, shutil, random
from tensorflow import keras
batch_size = 32
base_dir = pathlib.Path("aclImdb")
val_dir = base_dir / "val"
train_dir = base_dir / "train"
for category in ("neg", "pos"):
    os.makedirs(val_dir / category)
    files = os.listdir(train_dir / category)
    random.Random(1337).shuffle(files)
    num_val_samples = int(0.2 * len(files))
    val_files = files[-num_val_samples:]
    for fname in val_files:
        shutil.move(train_dir / category / fname,
                    val_dir / category / fname)

train_ds = keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/train", batch_size=batch_size
)
val_ds = keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/val", batch_size=batch_size
)
test_ds = keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/test", batch_size=batch_size
)
text_only_train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
```

preparing integer sequence datasets

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

max_length = 600
max_tokens = 20000
text_vectorization = layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=max_tokens,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=max_length,
)
text_vectorization.adapt(text_only_train_ds)

int_train_ds = train_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=4)
int_val_ds = val_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=4)
int_test_ds = test_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=4)

embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_tokens, output_dim=256)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64")
embedded = layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_tokens, output_dim=256)(inputs)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32))(embedded)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("embeddings_bidir_gru.keras",
                                    save_best_only=True)
]
model.fit(int_train_ds, validation_data=int_val_ds, epochs=2, callbacks=callbacks)
model = keras.models.load_model("embeddings_bidir_gru.keras")
print(f"Test acc: {model.evaluate(int_test_ds)[1]:.3f}")
```

My "addition" to the code is this part. After the model is ran, i take out a sentence like this:

```
ds = int_val_ds.take(1)     # int_val_ds is the dataframe that is already vectorized to numbers
for sentence, label in ds:  # example is (sentence, label)
  print(sentence.shape, label)

>> (32, 600) tf.Tensor([1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

So it's a batch of 32 sentences with 36 corresponding labels
If I look at the shape of one element

```
sentence[2].shape

>> TensorShape([600])
```

If I type

```
model.predict(sentence[2])

>> array([[0.49958456],
       [0.50042397],
       [0.50184965],
       [0.4992085 ],...
       [0.50077164]], dtype=float32)
```

with 600 elements. I was expecting a single number between 0 and 1. What went wrong?

Comment: Show the nlp keras model

Comment: I added it, thank you.

Comment: Do you pad the sequence to the input shape

Comment: Try to reshape your input array : model.predict(tf.reshape(sentence[2] , [1 , 600] );

Comment: Thank you, it worked. What you wrote is a comment or an answer? I am new here and I don't know all the ins and outs. I ask because I see no button to upvote it.

Comment: @AdrianMureșan Welcome to SO :) Just to answer your question, this was a comment. Also it's likely that Tou You didn't see your comment, when you want to say something to somebody who isn't the author of the post you need to add `@user`  to your comment with the name of the user (it will suggest the name when you start typing). If you want, you could tell Tou You that if they write an answer you'll be happy to select and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing @Tou You comment

```
model.predict(tf.reshape(sentence[2] , [1 , 600] )
```